# Move folders and files to Shared Drive (Google Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to move few folders and its contents from My Drive to Shared Drive (specific location). I am able to execute similar code without any issues if folders are moved from MyDrive to another MyDrive location. However, it is not the same for Shared Drive. I understand that I cannot execute "addFolder() or addFile()", so upon reading some forums, it appears that I have to use makeCopy() instead. I have never executed scripts in Shared Drive but heard the behavior is different from My Drive.

I am using the code below. My issues are as follows:
1. makeCopy() does not seem to work.
2. How can I get the creation date from Shared Drive

Here's my test file: *https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xznoTAH2yS-Xnf-b3cCc0j8vxa9jS10WP1HjQapzNw/edit?usp=sharing*

Your input and help is greatly appreciated!

```
function moveFolders() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetIDhere');
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet11');
      var range = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
      var values = range.getValues();

      for (var i = 0; i <= values.length-1; i++) {
        var folderid = values[i][0];
        var sdDriveId = values[i][1];
        var moveDate = values[i][2];
        var comments = values[i][3];

        if (moveDate != "" ) {continue;}  // if date exists, skip.
        if (folderid == "" || sdDriveId == "") {   // if source and target ids are missing, post message
         sheet.getRange(i+2,4).setValue('Missing Value');
        }
        else {
          var source_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid).getFiles(); //source folder
          var dest_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sdDriveId); //destination folder

          while (source_Folder.hasNext()) {
            var file = source_Folder.next();
            var destination = file.makeCopy(name,dest_Folder);
            var date = destination.getDateCreated();
            sheet.getRange(i+2,4,1,2).setValues([ [date, "Processed"] ]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I tested your code and it did copy the files into the Shared Drive. What role do you have in this Drive?

Comment: I was given a Manager role.

Comment: That's odd, I recommend you or the admin to contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en), since the code works.

Comment: @Jescanellas, Thank you for checking my code. I also tried Tanaike's code (makeCopy()) but no luck. I am thinking that it could be my access to Drive API or Google Oauth Scope, probably missing something. I'll ask around and do more research on this. Again, thank you!